# Unexpected high impedance output

Tags: verilog, test-bench, register-transfer-level

I'm writing an ALU for a processor I'm designing (first RTL project) and I'm getting a high impedance output on `ALU_out` when I run my testbench, even though the flags do get set and are output correctly.

```
       module alu(
        input clk,
        input reset,
        input [7:0] A, B,
        input [3:0] Op_Sel,
        output [7:0] ALU_out,
        output C, V, N, Z
    );
    
    reg [8:0] Result = 0;
    reg [8:0] cn_temp = 0;
    reg [7:0] v_temp = 0;
    reg carry = 0;
    reg overflow = 0;
    reg negative = 0; 
    reg zero = 0;

    assign ALU_Out = Result[7:0];
    assign C = carry;
    assign V = overflow;
    assign N = negative;
    assign Z = zero;
    
    always @*
     begin
       if (reset)
        begin
           Result = 0;
           cn_temp = 0;
           v_temp = 0;
           carry = 0;
           overflow = 0;
           negative = 0;
           zero = 0;
        end
     end
    
    always @(posedge clk)
     begin
          case(Op_Sel)
          4'b0000: // Addition
      begin
           Result = A + B; 
       negative = Result[7];
       zero = (Result[7:0] == 8'b00000000);
       carry = Result[8];
       v_temp = A[6:0] + B[6:0];
       overflow = v_temp[7] ^ carry;
      end
      .
      .
      //The rest of the instructions
      .
      .
      .
         endcase

      
       end


   endmodule

//My testbench

module alu_testbench();

reg clk;
reg reset;
reg [7:0] A;
reg [7:0] B;
reg [3:0] Op_Sel;
wire [7:0] ALU_out;
wire C, V, N, Z;

always begin
#1
clk = ~clk;
end

initial begin
clk = 0;
reset = 0;
#1
reset = 1;
#1
reset = 0;
end

initial begin
#10
A=2;
B=3;
Op_Sel = 4'b0000;
#10
A=1;

end


alu alu (
    .clk(clk),
    .A(A),
    .B(B),
    .Op_Sel(Op_Sel),
    .ALU_out(ALU_out),
    .C(C),
    .V(V),
    .N(N),
    .Z(Z));

endmodule
```

I believe I connected up the module to the testbench (through a wire), so why am I getting high impedance on `ALU_out`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky typo.  You mistakenly used an upper-case "O" in the `ALU_Out` signal name.  Since Verilog is case-sensitive, this is a different signal from `ALU_out`.  It is not mandatory to declare all signals in Verilog.  However, you can use the following compiler directive in your code to help catch this type of common problem:

```
`default_nettype none
```

Your simulator should generate an error.

To fix it, change:

```
assign ALU_Out = Result[7:0];
```

to:

```
assign ALU_out = Result[7:0];
```

---

My simulators also generated a warning message because you didn't drive the `reset` input of `alu`.  Here is the fix:

```
alu alu (
    .clk(clk),
    .reset(reset), /// <------ add this
    .A(A),
    .B(B),
    .Op_Sel(Op_Sel),
    .ALU_out(ALU_out),
    .C(C),
    .V(V),
    .N(N),
    .Z(Z));
```